# Дефисное/слитное/раздельное написание в названии "пейзажмастер"

Tags: орфография, лексика, приложение, дефис, слитно-раздельно-дефис

Ответьте, пожалуйста, какие правила орфографии могут действовать в случае написания названия "Пейзажмастер". Должно ли писаться это слово через дефис, как в случае "веб-мастер", "мастер-класс", слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 1):

Слитно оно писаться точно не будет, пишется через дефис, потому что пейзаж — это приложение. И тут два нарицательных существительных. Аналогично пейзаж-панорама.

Comment: М-м-м... Довольно спорное утверждение. А почему тогда "брандвахта" слитно пишется? С заимствованными словами все куда как сложнее. А здесь аккурат два таких...

Comment: Вот и я не могу разобраться... По идее, должно писаться через дефис, та как это - "сложное существительное, имеющее значение одного слова и состоящее из двух самостоятельно употребляющихся существительных, соединенных без помощи соединительных гласных о и е"(по аналогии с "дизель-мотор", "кафе-ресторан", "премьер-министр", "генерал-майор"). Но с другой стороны почему в слова "спортмастер", "спортинвентарь" ... пишутся слитно??? Если есть на форме лингвисты, подскажите, пожалуйста, как же все-таки правильно написать название "пейзаж-мастер"

Answer (score 0):

Если напишете "мастер по пейзажам", то ошибки точно не будет :)

Comment: :))) Безусловно, с радостью бы. Но надо понять как пишется "пейзаж-мастер". Спасибо.

Comment: Чисто эстетически для меня приятнее написание через дефис в данном случае.

Answer (score 0):

Слова "спортмастер", "спортинвентарь" пишутся слитно, так как это сокращённые слова "спортивный + инвентарь", "спортивный + мастер", по аналогии "пейзажмастер" пишется слитно — "пейзажный мастер", написание через дефис не считаю возможным,  так как нельзя уравнять эти понятия: "пейзаж И мастер", все-таки главное слово "мастер", (мастер какой? пейзажный) Р/S Рада буду ознакомиться с ссылкой на автора и академический ответ. Самой интересно.